# Temporary table for deletion

Tags: oracle

I have to use a PL_SQL anonymous block to delete rows in a lot of tables.
Every table is related to the main table "TABLE1", and I cannot add CASCADE DELETE. I have to do something like

```
DELETE FROM table2 WHERE foreign_key in (SELECT ID FROM table1 WHERE ...).
DELETE FROM table3 WHERE foreign_key in (SELECT ID FROM table1 WHERE ...).
...
```

The "SELECT ID.." query may take several minute, does it make sense to put all the ID in a temporary table or something like that? So I can execute the "select" query only once.
There are alternatives?

Comment: Have you tried to do it using the result cache: `DELETE FROM tableX WHERE foreign_key in (SELECT /*+ result_cache */ ID FROM table1 WHERE ...).`?

Comment: Inside the select query, I also have a sorting and a rownum filter. I'm not sure the result_cache hint is not recalculated every time

Comment: If the select is identical the result should not be recalculated...

Answer (score 0):

If

```
select id from table1 where ....
```

takes a lot of time, then *it depends*. The result will probably be cached so the next execution (while deleting from `table3`) won't last that long.

Won't cost much to test it. Delete a couple of tables *the old way* then create a "temporary" table using CTAS

```
create table ids as
  select id from table1 where ...
```

and use it in `DELETE` statements. You don't even need an index as you have to perform full table scan anyway.

Then choose a better option.

Comment: How can I create a table inside an anymous pl-sql code? I mean, between tags DECLARE/BEGIN/END

Comment: Using dynamic SQL, i.e. `execute immediate`. Don't do that. Create a table (using SQL Plus, SQL Developer, TOAD or whichever tool you use), populate it with rows, and use it in the procedure. Delete (truncate, drop ... pick one) it when you don't need it any more.

Comment: I can only use an anonymous block. Cannot create table outside it

Comment: Why not? How do you know you'll manage to create it from PL/SQL? Do you have CREATE TABLE privileges?

Comment: Business rules: I can only send this anonymous block to someone who will execute it. No ddl is admitted

Comment: Well, you'll have to check whether the table (with that name) already exists. If so, what to do with it; is it yours or is it someone else's (for another purposes)? Are you allowed to use it? Not that it can't be done; it's just that such an approach is *bad practices* as far as Oracle is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is the use of `PL/SQL-Collections`:

```
DECLARE
  id_list SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST;
BEGIN
  SELECT ID 
    BULK COLLECT INTO id_list
    FROM table1 
   WHERE ...

  FORALL i IN id_list.FIRST..id_list.LAST
    DELETE FROM table2
    WHERE foreign_key = id_list(i);

  FORALL i IN id_list.FIRST..id_list.LAST
    DELETE FROM table3
    WHERE foreign_key = id_list(i);

  ...
END;
```